# internee evaluation

Tags: internship, toxic-culture

Does bad internee evaluation have any effect on your future jobs? i did my first internship of 4 weeks and my supervisor was on his sick leave for 1st week. then for 2nd week he showed me the bare minimum. for 3rd week he went on vacation and last week i was sent to another dept now he has rated every thing ‘fair’ on internee evaluation and poor on ‘seeks new knowledge’ and i’m feeling so disappointed with where i went wrong with this. when i first started and asked what ‘work’ i’ll do they said i won’t be getting any work as i’m an intern but i don’t understand this evaluation either

Comment: It might effect your ability to get another internship, as that would be relevant experience, but if you need assistance to perform job functions you should remedy that situation. You should take the feedback back seriously. If you don’t understand, ask for additional feedback, so you can improve

Answer (score 1):

> Does bad internee evaluation have any effect on your future jobs?

That's mostly up to you. If you get a bad evaluation you can reject it, deem it unfair, consider it someone else's fault, etc. OR you can try to accept it and analyze it, honestly look at would could have done differently and learn from it.

It you manage to do this, you will grow as a person and that will improve your chances for future employment and job satisfaction.

Whether you put it on your resume or not, is up to you.

One of my favorite questions  for candidates is "tell me about a time where you screwed up" or "tell me about a time when you had maneuver a difficult situation". Everyone makes mistakes or ends up in a tight spot every once in a while. That's normal and expected. The key here is how you manage these situations.

Answer (score 0):

It may affect your options with that company. Though it does not sound like a company you actually want to work for.

If you simply leave it off your resume, it won't affect you when interviewing with anyone else.